# What is the easiest way to export data from a live Google App Engine application?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, frameworks

I'm especially interested in solutions with source code available (Django independency is a plus, but I'm willing to hack my way through)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, of course, write your own handler. Other than that, your options currently are limited to:

- [gae-rest](http://github.com/fczuardi/gae-rest/tree/master), which provides a RESTful interface to the datastore.
- [approcket](http://code.google.com/p/approcket/), a tool for replicating between MySQL and App Engine.
- The amusingly named [GAEBAR](http://aralbalkan.com/1784) - Google App Engine Backup and Restore.

Comment: Google is reporting that aralbalkan.com contains malware.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: New version of Google AppEngine supports data import to and export from the online application natively. In their terms this is called `upload_data` and `download_data` respectively (names of subcommands of `appcfg.py`).

Please refer to Google documentation [how to export and import data from/to GAE](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html). This is probably the better way to do it today.

My old answer is below:

---

I use [to_xml()](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/appengine/docs/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_to_xml) method of the Model class to export the datastore.

```
class XmlExport(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        objects=MyModel.all().fetch(1000)
        xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<site>\n'
        for o in objects:
            xml = xml + o.to_xml()
        xml = xml + '</site>'
        self.response.headers['Content-Type']='text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        self.response.out.write(xml)
```